# How to call css into div class inner div class?

Tags: html, css

I try to call css into div class inner div class. Please solve my code?

Html code :

```
<div class="underpost_3c_head">
    <div class="underpost_3c_head_title">hhh1 </div>

    <div class="underpost_2nd_page_head_title">
        <div class="2nd_page_head_result">hhh</div>
        <div class="2nd_page_head_result">hhh</div>
        <div class="2nd_page_head_result">hhh</div>
        <div class="2nd_page_head_result">hhh</div>
    </div>

    <div class="underpost_3rd_page_head_title">
        <div class="3rd_page_head_result">hhh</div>
        <div class="3rd_page_head_result">hhh</div>
        <div class="3rd_page_head_result">hhh</div>
        <div class="3rd_page_head_result">hhh</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

---

How can i select all class?
I try :

```
.2nd_page_head_result {
  width: 110px;
  padding-left:5px;
}
```

and

```
div.2nd_page_head_result {
  padding-left:5px;
}
```

But it's not working. Please help me solve this.

Comment: class names starting with digits need to be escaped in css. For instance, if the class is `2nd`, the css selector needs to be `.\32 nd`.

Comment: Thank you wogsland

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot start class names and/or IDs with a number.

```css
.nd_page_head_result {
  width: 110px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  background: wheat;
}
```

```html
<div class="underpost_3c_head">
  <div class="underpost_3c_head_title">hhh1</div>

  <div class="underpost_2nd_page_head_title">
    <div class="nd_page_head_result">hhh</div>
    <div class="nd_page_head_result">hhh</div>
    <div class="nd_page_head_result">hhh</div>
    <div class="nd_page_head_result">hhh</div>
  </div>

  <div class="underpost_3rd_page_head_title">
    <div class="3rd_page_head_result">hhh</div>
    <div class="3rd_page_head_result">hhh</div>
    <div class="3rd_page_head_result">hhh</div>
    <div class="3rd_page_head_result">hhh</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

There is a way around this, however:

```
[class="3rd_page_head_result"] {color: red;}
```

https://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/

Comment: My intent was to contrast the way he had done it (non-working) viz using a class name that did not start with a number, to demonstrate visibly that just that one change made the difference.. It wasn't a half-arsed answer, but rather a compare-and-contrast. Fair 'nuff?